# Computing the first k powers of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

If I want to compute the first `k` powers (say, `k = 10`) of some matrix `A`, using `matrix.power` from the `matrixcalc` package, would I really need to write `A2 <- matrix.power(A, 2)`, `A3 <- matrix.power(A, 3)`, ..., `A10 <- matrix.power(A, 10)`? It seems a bit tedious to me, but I tried to avoid loops, which I understand is recommended in R, because it is not efficient. Would I be able to do some magic with `apply` functions? Basically, I would need the sum of some specific entry from all the powers of the matrix `A` up to a `k`.

Comment: Try `Vectorize(function(x) matrix.power(A, x))(2:5)` or `lapply(2:10, matrix.power, x = A)`

Comment: The stuff you have heard about loops is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `lapply`

```
library(matrixcalc)
lst1 <- lapply(2:100, matrix.power, x = A)
```

and then get the sum with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, lst1)
```

Comment: Great answer! Would there be an equally simple way to get the scalar product of some specific entry in the matrices `1 - lst1[[i]]` for i = 1, ..., k in your example?

Comment: @Peter if you need elementwise product, use `Reduce("*", lst1)`

Comment: Thanks! Would I also be able to do that for `1 - lst1` (that is, `lst1[[i]] = 1 - lst1[[i]]`) rather than `lst1`?

Comment: @Peter your code is not clear to me.  Do you want to update all the list elements by subtracting from 1?  In that case `lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) 1- x)`

Comment: Exactly! I was not sure whether it was necessary to call lapply twice to do that. Thanks!